# How to create two custom table cell buttons?

Tags: ios, swift

I am preparing a table in which when I swipe the cell I need to get two rounded buttons. Each button should have one image and and a label.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    var hello = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Image") { (action, indexPath) in

    // do some action

    if let buttonImage = UIImage(named: "Image") {
        //  self.bgColor = UIColor.imageWithBackgroundColor(image: buttonImage, bgColor: UIColor.blueColor())
    }
    return editButtonItem()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are some problems with your code :

1. You return the result of `editButtonItem()` method, which basically discards your `hello` action. I'm gonna assume from the name of it, that this method returned a single action, and not two as you wanted.
2. In your action handler, you tried to set the background on `self`. Blocks capture variables from their parent scope, so `self` in this block didn't relate to `hello` action, but rather to the class in which your `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` method was implemented.

How to achieve what you need (two buttons with title and image) :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    var firstAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "First") { (action, indexPath) in
        // action handler code here
        // this code will be run only and if the user presses the button
        // The input parameters to this are the action itself, and indexPath so that you know in which row the action was clicked
    }
    var secondAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Second") { (action, indexPath) in
        // action handler code here
    }

    firstAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "firstImageName")!)
    secondAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"secondImageName")!)

    return [firstAction, secondAction]
}
```

We create two separate actions, assign their background colors to use pattern images and return an array containing both our actions. This is the most you can do to alter the appearance of `UITableViewRowAction` - we can see [from the docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewrowaction), that this class doesn't inherit from `UIView`.

If you wanted to customize the appearance more, you should look for an external library or implement your own solution from the scratch.